# Where are Windows 7 Passwords Stored?

Tags: windows-7, passwords

Where are Microsoft Windows 7 passwords and credentials stored on disk?

I would like to physically verify  that the Users group does not have access to files containing system passwords.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Windows account details are stored in the [SAM registry hive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Accounts_Manager). It stores passwords using a one-way-hash (either LM Hash, which is old and weak, or NTLM hash which is newer and stronger.)

The SAM hive file is located at `%WinDir%\system32\config\sam`. This directory, and it parents, are by default inaccessible to non-administrative users. However it is vulnerable to offline attacks (e.g. booting a LiveCD and manually modifying the binary data. For example with the [ONTPRE](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) tool.)

Answer (score 4):

They are stored per user in C:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\credentials and also in C:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Vault . Since this is in a user directory it's safe to say only the user and computer/domain admins have access to it. Not to mention it is also encrypted.

Comment: "It's encrypted" is really all that needs to be said for your peace of mind, I should hope :)

Comment: Encryption isn't hard to break with some reading on the net - I found this out earlier this year at school

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102716 I hate you people for beating me to this answer.  Unless I was gunna answer it wrong in which case, thanks :)

Comment: Neither of these locations relate to where Windows stores user account passwords.

Comment: @ekaj Depends on the type of encryption, AES 256 like used in kerberos exchanges (windows logins) is VERY difficult if not impossible to break.

Comment: @Kyle: True, it may be difficult, but if someone really needs into something or wants in I'm sure they could use a cloud and use brute force/rainbow tables/ something =p

Comment: @ekaj Like Kyle said, it depends on the type.  Some types (normally ones that are dealing with mass market consumer products like CSS that almost have to have holes in them to work as intended, or some forms that are meant to be encrypted and decrypted by hand like the Caesar Cypher) are relatively easy to break.  Modern strong computer encryption like TwoFish is very hard to break.

Comment: @ekaj Rainbow tables are fantastic for dealing with short hashes.  They do not work well when dealing with much more than that.  Brute forcing modern cryptography with a long key is hard.  By which I mean be prepared to wait for months or years if you have a spare supercomputer lying around and expect to not see the answer in your lifetime if you don't.

Comment: I think it was going to take 22 days or so for one computer to crack an 8 digit password using every possible ascii character, I think a cloud could accomplish it

Comment: you can use Cain's LSA Secrets dumper to get the admin password in cleartext without needing to decrypt anything

Comment: @ekaj define crack?  If you mean you want to generate every possible 8 digit password, I suspect you could do it in *much* less than 22 days on a decent desktop.  If you mean actually then try those to see which one decrypts your target file, that depends on how long each attempt takes, and that would take *much* longer.  Also, 8 digits is not considered long for a strong password, and the difficult goes up exponentially with each extra character.

Comment: C:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\credentials @Kyle:
While the passwords are hashed and then stored in the directory, the password can often be recovered by using rainbow tables (up to 14 charecters). Even if the file containing the hashes is encrypted, the key used for the encryption must be stored somewhere on the drive and there has to be code refrenceing the location of <b>that</b> key so that the system can find the hash value when the user attempts to log on.