# Windows 8 Password Storing

Tags: windows, windows-8, passwords, storage, cloud

I was wondering if someone could please shed some light on how Windows 8 stores password or if it does at all? I believe that Windows 8 has more cloud features and that it goes by your Windows Live ID, so does that mean it uses the password for your Live ID for when you login?

Comment: Windows 8 stores your password in nearly exactly the same way that Windows 7 does.

Comment: Password for What?

Comment: @Moab When you start Windows 8 and it asks for your login...

Comment: Can someone please give me a definitive answer? I use my MS account for my Windows 8 login...

Comment: Not sure but I assume it is encrypted in the SAM file like regular user accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8 stores your password the same way Windows 7 does or recent versions did.

If you use a local account, nothing changed at all.

If you use Microsoft account, it works similar to a domain account. Your password to Live ID account is cached so that you can login Windows even if there's no Internet connection. Windows will synchronize the passwords when you're online.

Of course, your password to Microsoft account is used by Windows to authenticate on SkyDrive to synchronize your settings and, possibly, files. Thus it works seamless, and you're not required to enter your password yourself.

Comment: Uhm, there were several ways of storing the user's password throughout the versions. Lanman, NTLMv1, NTLMv2 for a start.

Comment: Kerberos too, but don't think theres 'fallover' on Kerberos so I hazard a guess it's Kerberos with NTLM fallover

Comment: @HaydnWVN [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM#NTLM_and_Kerberos) is used in Active Directory domain, and falls back to NTLMv2.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov Does that also apply to Windows RT with just the Live ID?

Comment: For the lazy: [Where are Windows 7 passwords stored?](http://superuser.com/questions/367579/where-are-windows-7-passwords-stored)