# Lost admin account after windows update

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, administrator

My development machine was rebooted after a windows update recently and now I can't access my admin account.

I never reboot my machine except when forced by WU so I actually don't know if the problem is related to WU. Don't remember when I last used the admin account but it is probably a week or 2 ago.

Normally I run in a normal user account and keep an admin command prompt open to deal with admin tasks.

What happens now is:

- If I do something that triggers the UAC and enter user ".\admin" and password I get the message
  `Logon failure: unknown user or bad password`
- If I do `RUNAS /user:.\admin cmd` I get the message
  `RUNAS ERROR: Unable to acquire user password`

Any idea what the problem is?

It is not a big problem since I can call in a domain admin but I am curious about what has happened and why UAC and RUNAS show different error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SAM file might have been damaged.
Explanation on [SAM]: [Where are Windows 7 Passwords Stored?](https://superuser.com/questions/367579/where-are-windows-7-passwords-stored) is available here.

Comment: There were no error messages or event logs about corrupt SAM file but problem was solved by resetting the admin password. Strange it can happen like this. What would I do if I didn't have the domain administrator?